# Testing if data has a binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics

I need help testing that data has a binomial distribution? I am not quite sure how to do this. Question as below:
A hundred students take a test on which there are 5 questions, each to be answered simply yes or no. The number of students getting 0 -> 5 questions right are as follows:
no of correct answers - 0   1   2   3   4   5
frequency -   2   11  20  45  21   1

Test the hypothesis that the no of correct answers has a binomial distribution?

I am just starting a statistics course (after not doing it for many years)  I have done a similar question with testing data as a poisson dist. but I'm unsure what formula to use to compute the expected values, and then would I perform the 'Chi ^2' test?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- You are looking for estimates of the parameters of the parameters $n$ and $p$ of a binomial distribution.
- $n$ will be the number of questions, i.e. $5$.
- $p$ will be the proportion of questions of questions answered correctly, i.e. the total number of marks, which you can calculate, divided by $5 \times 100$.
- You can now calculate the expected number of students getting $x$ marks if there is a Binomial distribution: $100{n \choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$
- You can now set up your test.  You might want to watch out for issues such the number of degrees of freedom and cells with small expected numbers

Comment: Good tips (+1) - just to add one thing: in general you want the expected value of each cell to be $\geq 5$ so that the Chi-squared test statistic is reasonably well approximated by a chi-squared distribution (Henry alluded to this in the last bullet). Since you have 100 observations, you need to set up your bins so that there is at least a 5% chance of a sample landing in each cell. Also, since you are estimating $p$ from your data, you need to subtract an extra degree of freedom from your test.